# South schema and data migrations via a build script executed by Jenkins on remote server (AWS EC2)

Tags: django, postgresql, jenkins, migration, django-south

Can someone shed some light on how one might go about doing a South migration (both schema and data) on a server, e.g. AWS EC2 instance running both Postgres and a Django app (via nginx) servers, through a build script executed by Jenkins. Jenkins hooks in to a git repo, pulls the repo upon any push to it and runs the build script.

Does the following procedure make sense?

1. Locally, do changes to models and create migrations (via South, i.e. `python manage.py schemamigration appname --auto`/`datamigration appname` + edits to `forwards` and `backwards` functions in the generated migration scripts needed for datamigration).
2. Apply migrations locally to see if they work.
3. Add, commit and push the migration scripts and modified models files to remote git repo.
4. Get Jenkins to apply the migrations via its build script.

How can Jenkins apply migrations to the database is the main question? Am I right in thinking that the Jenkins build script should activate a virtual environment, set `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment variable (which contains the database settings), install all requirements (pip install), and then do a `python manage.py migrate`, thereby applying a series of schema+data migrations as per the migration scripts? Followed by this, Jenkins can copy the Django/Python files pulled from the git repo into its workspace, to the right folders on the EC2 instance, and then restart nginx?

I am unsure as to how Jenkins, Postgres, and nginx interact when it comes to migrations. Any best practices/standard way of doing South migrations with Jenkins executing the migrations would be very helpful!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When setting up Jenkins to deploy on your server, generally all you would need to do is include a call to `python manage.py migrate` in the build script.

For example in Jenkins ([reference](http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2014/04/19/continuous-integration-server-for-django-using-jenkins/)):

1. In the Build section click the Add build step button.
2. Select Execute shell from the drop-down.
3. Adjust the following script to your needs and enter it in the Command text area.

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
source /webapps/hello_django/activate     # Activate the virtualenv
cd /webapps/hello_django/trunk/
pip install -r REQUIREMENTS.txt           # Install or upgrade dependencies
python manage.py migrate                  # Apply South's database migrations
python manage.py compilemessages          # Create translation files
python manage.py collectstatic --noinput  # Collect static files
sudo apachectl graceful                   # Restart the server, e.g. Apache
python manage.py test --noinput app1 app2 # Run the tests
```

So in general when you refer to steps such as installing requirements, setting up the virtualenv, these are all steps that you will be orchestrating as one or more build steps.

While it would add complexity, I would also recommend having Jenkins first deploy to a staging environment which has a fresh copy of the production database and is an exact copy (i.e. in terms of OS) as the production system. If the migrations apply successfully and the test suite passes on staging, then you can proceed to kick off a build that will deploy in production.

Comment: I faced some problems doing datamigrations. Converting a many to many field to a sorted many to many of the same name required many stages: add new sorted m2m field, move data from m2m to sorted m2m, delete m2m (name of the sorted m2m is different), make a further sorted m2m of the same name as the original m2m, move data from old to new sorted m2m, and delete old sorted m2m. Am I insane? Applying the migrations happened in steps however for me, instead of a single `python manage.py migrate`. South must handle multiple data migration at once = my data migration scripts need mods!

Comment: Complex migrations of that kind do require special care to be taken but ultimately there should be no difference between calling `migrate` in your development environment and in production--you will need to design your migrations such that they run in order and without issue. Also a very good idea to point it at a staging environment first before committing to it in production.